# Convert a string to a color hex code

Tags: r, hex

Is there a function which converts a string to a color hex code?

For example:

> "foo" -> "#F123FA"

Converting a number with 4 digits into a hex code would be also totally fine, but the problem is that my numbers are very similar.

Does someone know a good solution?

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Why do you need that?

Comment: What is the nature of these strings and/or numbers? Are you trying to move from color names to hex codes? If so, what kind of numbers are these? If not, can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish -- What is the nature of the inputs, and what is the expected relationship between the inputs and the outputs?

Comment: I've got a list of IDs with 4 digits and would like to dynamically assign a color for each number. My first idea was to concat "#FF" + number to get a hex code, but the problem is that there are some similar numbers, so that the colors look similar as well.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution on my own with this sha1 hint:

```
library(digest)
a <- 'test'
print(a)
a <- sapply(a, digest, algo = "sha1")
hex <- paste0('#', substr(a, 0, 6))
print(hex)
```